# Where can I find a huge collection of YAML files for unit testing?

Tags: unit-testing, parsing, f#, yaml

I started writing a YAML parser with F# and I would like to test it.
So I was wondering if someone knows where I can find an archive containing hundreds or thousands of random YAML files in order to create unit tests for my project.

Comment: Did you finish this parser?  Is it open source?

Comment: Crazy idea, maybe a use for ChatGPT...

Answer (score 2):

You could do a google search for [filetype:yaml](http://www.google.dk/search?q=filetype%3ayaml) and then spider those.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you're probably better off generating them yourself, as finding a huge collection of such file seems quite unlikely.

Comment: I can't really generate them myself. The goal being to have tricky stuff that I would not think about ;)